# Calculating shopping cart discounts

Tags: ruby, e-commerce

I have a method that checks to see if a hash of given items should have discounts applied and if so, determines and returns the discount:

```
def get_discounts
  @items.each do |name, attr|
    @specials.each do |special|
      while name == special.sale_item && attr[:quantity] >= special.quantity
        @discounts << special.discount
        attr[:quantity] = attr[:quantity] - special.quantity
      end  
    end  
  end
  determine_discount
end

def determine_discount
  if @discounts.empty?
    @discounts = 0
  else
    @discounts = @discounts.inject(:+) 
  end   
end
```

This works perfectly, but is there a more concise way to write it?  I'm looking especially at the two `each` loops.  I'm also a bit iffy about the `while` loop - it was an `if` statement (`if name == special.sale_item`) but it felt like too much so I combined it into the `while` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with both of your suspected issues:

- **Pointless iteration through `@items` hash:** As you suspected, iterating through all entries of a hash defeats the purpose of a hash.  That takes O(*I* * *S*) time — the number of items times the number of specials.   Why not iterate through `@specials`, then look up the item by name?  That's only O(*S*).
- **while loop:** The loop can be replaced with arithmetic.

In addition, I would like to point out some more problems:

- **Surprising side-effect in getter:** By convention, any method named `get_*()` is assumed to have no side-effects.  However, `get_discounts()` alters `@items`, reducing their quantity.  If that is intentional, you should rename the method to `apply_discounts()` or something even more suggestive that there is a side-effect.
- **Abuse of instance variable:** `@discounts` is assumed to be pre-initialized to an empty array before `get_discounts()` is called.  `get_discounts()` populates the array, then calls `determine_discount()`, which converts it into a scalar.  That indicates that `@discounts` is not storing the state of the object, so using an instance variable for that purpose is abuse.

Here is a revised version of the code:

```
def get_discounts
  discount = 0
  @specials.each do |special|
    if item = @items[special.sale_item]
      multiples = (item[:quantity] / special.quantity).floor
      discount += multiples * special.discount

      # Suspicious side-effect...
      # item[:quantity] -= multiples * special.quantity
    end
  end
  return discount
end
```

Comment: great answer, thank you - actually i had remedied the 'side-effect' but thanks for pointing that out.  I did `count = info[:quantity]` and then `count = count - special.quantity` but your way is nicer.  Cheers, really appreciate the push in the right direction!